# How to understand the integral over complex plane .

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

> Suppose $f(z)$ is in $C^{\infty}$ with compact support in $C$ .  Then $$u(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{z-\zeta} \,dm(\zeta)$$ satisfied $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{z}}(z)=f(z)$$
>
> with $m(\zeta)$ denote the Lebesgue measure in $C$ . Also , the function $f(z)=\frac1z$ is integrable over compact sets in $C$ .

The discussion above was in Stein's functional analysis Page$_{284}$ . However , I haven't encounter the case when we need to integral over some region . So , what is the definition of $$\int_C f(z) \, dm(z)$$ Does it mean $$\int_{R^2} u(x,y)+iv(x,y)\, dxdy$$ ?

Comment: Assuming your $C$ is $\mathbb{C}$, yes.